# How to I find CAUFVD structure where filled in project builder of project system module?

Tags: sap-erp

I want to find CAUFVD-AUFNR field where set. How can I find this?

The CAUFVD-AUFNR field in simulation of project builder in project system set as wrong value. I want to find out why it comes happen.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use Where Used feature.

[image: Where Used]

Good luck searching, because there are plenty of places where this field is referenced.

[image: The result of Where Used]